# Visual Studio Escapes the third condition of Linq Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Visual Studio c# does not check for the third condition of the if statement userName should not be existed before entering the condition. I have cleaned the solution cleared the cashes but still I get the same result of ignoring the third condition of Linq statement

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create( RegisterAsReqModel registerAsReqModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //Create application user
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registerAsReqModel.UserName, Email = registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress};
                //assgin user to user type
                user.UserType = "Req";
                var result1 = db.Users.Where(m => m.UserName.Equals(registerAsReqModel.UserName)).FirstOrDefault();
                var result2 = db.Users.Where(m => m.Email.Equals(registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress)).FirstOrDefault();
                var result3 = from app in db.Users where app.Email.Equals(registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress) && app.UserType.Equals("Req") && app.UserName.Equals(registerAsReqModel.UserName) select app;
                 // 
                if (!result3.Any())
                {
                    UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
                    {
                        RequireUniqueEmail = false,

                    };
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, registerAsReqModel.Password);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Req");
                        db.RegisterAsReqModels.Add(registerAsReqModel);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
                else if ((result1 != null) && (result2 !=null))
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email Address and UserName Both Exists!");
                } else if(db.Users.Where(m=>m.Email.Equals(registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress)).FirstOrDefault()!= null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email Address Exists!");

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName  Exists!");
                }

            }

            return View(registerAsReqModel);
        }
```

Model Class:

```
public class RegisterAsReqModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have always had issues comparing string with `==`. Have you tried using `string1.Equals(string2)` ?

Comment: okay I will try that

Comment: Yes I did that ` var result3 = from app in db.Users where app.Email.Equals(registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress) && app.UserType.Equals("Req") && app.UserName.Equals(registerAsReqModel.UserName) select app;` still getting the same problem

Comment: can you provide some sample data and code that is throwing exceptions in your question please. Class for Users would be helpful too

Comment: would that be enough or do you need more specific classes , data are manually input-ed from form

Comment: using the debugger, can you check the values of registerAsReqModel and see if all of the elements have correct values. Use the Immediate Window to check each condition and see what you get

Comment: yes all values are passed correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205698/discussion-between-jawad-and-ghassa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> result of ignoring the third condition of Linq statement

This happens because first or second condition in your linq is coming up with a false. When you have a false in multi condition statement, parser will ignore the remaining conditions. Changing the conditions based on how they should be executed will result in more likely result.

Also, you are using if and else if with same conditions. I would recommend combining them as well and display the error as a combination at the end.

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //Create application user
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registerAsReqModel.UserName, Email = registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress };
        //assgin user to user type
        user.UserType = "Req";
        var result1 = db.Users.Where(m => m.UserName.Equals(registerAsReqModel.UserName)).FirstOrDefault();
        var result2 = db.Users.Where(m => m.Email.Equals(registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress)).FirstOrDefault();

        var result3 = from app in db.Users where app.UserType.Equals("Req") && app.Email.Equals(registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress) && app.UserName.Equals(registerAsReqModel.UserName) select app;
        // 
        if (result3 == null)
        {
            UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
            {
                RequireUniqueEmail = false,

            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, registerAsReqModel.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Req");
                db.RegisterAsReqModels.Add(registerAsReqModel);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        else if ((result1 != null) && (result2 != null))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (result2 != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Email Address Exists!");

            }
            else
            {
                sb.AppendLine("UserName  Exists!");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```